# Autowire CrudRepository - Error creating bean with Unsatisfied dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a very simple spring boot rest api and it is throwing error while autowiring the interface which is extending the CrudRepository. There are many question related to this and I tried the solutions provided still it is not able to resolve the issue. Here is the code of application

***Entry Point:***

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.example.controllers", "com.example.entities", "com.example.repositories", "com.example.services"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repositories")
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

***Entity***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "dob", nullable = false)
    private Date dateOfBirth;
}
```

***Controller***

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("app")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/count", produces = "application/json")
    public Long getCount() {
        return employeeService.getCount();
    }
}
```

***Service***

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepo employeeRepo;

    public Long getCount(){
        return employeeRepo.count();
    }
}
```

***Repository***

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepo extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {
}
```

In my opinion it should work, however it is giving me following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'employeeService': Error creating
> bean with name 'employeeService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed
> through field 'employeeRepo': Error creating bean with name
> 'employeeRepo' defined in com.example.repositories.EmployeeRepo
> defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on DemoApplication: Not a
> managed type: class com.example.entities.Employee

***EDIT***
There is no chance of misspelling the packg names as IntelliJ checks that. If it can not find the pckg then it highlights it in red.
[image]

Comment: If you will add empty constructor to entity class, will it help ? Also one constructor with all the fields, getters and setters for fields

Comment: @EnableJpaRepositories probably needs to include the entities package.

Comment: @AndrewS, I added "@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.example.entities", "com.example.repositories"})" still it is throwing same error.

Comment: @AndreiLisa, I added an empty constructor but getting the same error. I am not sure how the constructor would help in this case.

Comment: Package name typo?  Try putting all the classes in the same package.

Comment: typo is not possible, please see my edits. However, if all the classes are in same package then it is working properly.

Comment: Place your `@SpringBootApplication` in the `com.example` package. Remove all annotations except `@SpringBootApplication`. The `@Repository` on the Spring Data JPA repository is useless, it will only hurt your eyes, remove it. Assuming you are using Spring Boot 3.x make sure you have `jakarta.persistence` as the package imports and not `javax.persistence`.